# Twilio browser-to-browser conferencing web app

Tags: web, twilio

I am new to Twilio and need help for understanding how to build a web app for conferencing in the browser.

The users of the website should be able to schedule a conference call from the browser with specific expert. The expert should be able to join the call from the browser if he is able.

My question is what is the minimum number of Twilio phone numbers that I need for that case ?
Should every expert has its own Twilio phone number ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you want the conference calls to happen in the browser then you don't necessarily need any phone numbers. [Twilio Client](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript) can make browser to browser calls without the need for a phone number. You could also do video and audio conferences using [Twilio Video](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/javascript) (check out [these example collaboration applications](https://www.twilio.com/blog/open-source-video-apps-reactjs-ios-android)).

If you want these to be conference calls that people dial into, you could make this with one phone number and then have callers enter a unique code for the expert they want to talk to. If you want them to be able to dial straight through, then one number per expert would work too.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. I have one question about the conference calls. Is the phone number per conference room ? Or can I use only one phone number I schedule many simultaneous conferences for different people and experts ? Thanks.

Comment: You can schedule multiple simultaneous conferences from one number. You will have to decide how callers enter the particular conference (for example: a whitelist of phone numbers for a particular room or each caller must enter an identifier for the room they want to enter). To send the caller to a room you need to return a [`<Conference>` TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/conference) with the name of the room the caller is to join.